# Is it possible to make SMS attached Image linkable using MFMessageComposeViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible to make attached image linkable in SMS in iOS. Mean when user see the SMS with image that image can redirect to some url.Please, suggest.

Answer (score 1):

No, SMS does not support images at all. SMS is text only no markup allowed.

iOS does support MMS but the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) only supports SMS prior to iOS 7.

In iOS 7 you can have attachments, but the message will then be send as an MMS.

Comment: In iOS 7 MMS can be send, can't we make that image as linkable?

Comment: Not sure if you can link an URL to an image, you will have to read the documentation to see if that is possible: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have read the document, but there does not seems that we can do it. Any how thanks for your reply.